# Internet loss on host after running intensive app (e.g. expo-cli, create-react-app servers, etc)

Tags: node.js, networking, windows-10, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a bit of a problem and I'm having a really hard time of looking up info on the web.

**The problem**

When running network-intensive applications from WSL, after a while Windows 10 loses internet connectivity. Restarting LxssManager service restores internet connectivity.

This happens most often when using [`expo cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli). It sometimes also happened with `create-react-app` server, but recently I haven't had problems with that.

**What I've tried**

- pinging 8.8.8.8 (sometimes works, sometimes errors with `Network Unreachable`. Even when it works, Windows still doesn't have internet)
- Disabling IPv6
- Disabling power saving on the WiFi adapter
- Running script from cmder (as opposed to the integrated terminal of VsCode)
- Running script from WSL Bash
- Switching from wireless to ethernet (same problem)
- Updating/rolling back all network drivers
- Reinstalling WSL, node and related packages
- Reinstalling Windows

**Environment**

- Dell Latitude E5570 with Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 8260
- Windows 10 version 1809 build 17763.55 (also happened with the previous update)
- WSL Ubuntu installed from store
- Node.JS versions 8 through 11 (tested on all versions and same behaviour on all)

I don't know if this is an issue with WSL or an issue with my laptop / drivers / config, so I thought it's best to post here before posting an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Can you provide the steps to reporduce this error? What's your windows 10 build number? This issue can't be solved with one Q&A. You've to make an issue in GitHub/WSL or GitHub/expo-cli repository.

Comment: Well, the error simply appears when running `expo cli` after a couple of minutes. My build number is `17763.55`, as I've mentioned in the *Environment* section.

I've also posted in the `expo-cli` repo, but no one replied there - I'll post to the WSL repo as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I've only managed to find a workaround, by going into `services.msc` and restarting `LxssManager`. This fixes the issue most of the time, but sometimes the restart itself hangs up and a restart of the whole PC is the only solution.

Comment: @BogdanMariusCalapod 12/2019 and I’m experiencing the exact same problem on Windows 10 + WSL and the latest expo-cli (^3.9).
Windows seems to lose randomly the connection after some time of dev.
Thanks to your post, I restarted the LxssManager service and that worked, but it’s temporary until the problem happen again sometime later.
Did you find another durable solution yet?

Comment: I've since switched to the slow insider ring in order to use WSL2. Haven't done any Expo development on it, but after going through the technical differences between WSL1 and 2, it should work flawlessly here.

Comment: @jmpp have you found a beter solution or tried Windows Insider with WSL2?

Comment: @Daniel Nope, still the same. I found a workaround by installing Expo globally on my Windows environment (not WSL) and launch "expo start" from a Powershell instead of WSL.